# omniauth facebook uninitialzed constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth-facebook

I am following the rails cast video [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?autoplay=true) but when I try run my server I am getting a error "uninitialized constant OmniAuth (NameError)". When I remove this file the server starts and the home page is shown except the link to facebook login authentication returns a routing error "No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook" of course.

My question is similar to this stackoverlfow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643832/unicorn-and-omniauth-facebook-uninitialized-constant-omniauth) but mine is in development mode.

All code is the same I am wodnering what this is. Please help!

Full error is

```
C:/Sites/blog/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant OmniAuth (NameError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Sites/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Also if the /initializers/omniauth.rb is in its folder I cannot generate the user model I need to remove it to even do this?

I have the latest version of omniauth-facebook gem installed and ran bundle install.

Comment: `provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']` this line should be in your `initializers/devise.rb` file if you are using devise by any chance. also try to add more details

Comment: no just using the rails cast example and following documentation on github for omniauth and omniauth-facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have both omniauth and omniauth-facebook in your gemfile? like:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Comment: Yes both gems are installed.

Comment: this answer is actually right. It was my lack of understanding in the cmd line, and, putting the gem IN the gemfile. not just installing through the cmd line.